# CDN + WP Admin Query - .htaccess redirection

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess, cdn

Say I have a website at `https://www.example.com` and I am using a CDN. Now if I want the CDN URL to be `https://www.example.com/assets/...` and not `https://assets.example.com`, then what should I do?

Is it a good idea to create a redirection where the wp-admin will always get files from example.com and not `www.example.com`? `www.example.com` is pointed towards a CDN.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Is this possible? What `.htaccess` rules should I use for the same?

Comment: do you use a CDN or you want to setup it ?

Comment: want to set it up